# How can I create custom layout in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I have container repeated at more than view. 
How can I create this container just one time and implement its class using builder design pattern.

Example: I have TextView its color and text changed according to the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your common layout for your textView name it as layout_text_view.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="dark"
        type="Boolean" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:text="Some Random Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:textColor='@{dark?@color/white:@color/colorBlack}'
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xxxx_large"
        app:fontFamily="@font/sfprotext_bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can use this layout in your fragments with **include** tag like this

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
        app:dark='@{true}'
        />
```

You can use many values in data tag which will change your common ayout_text_view.xml file.

Note- I have assumed you may be using data binding in your project if not then paste

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

in your build.gradel(App level) . In android tag

Comment: How can I use builder design pattern to implement this layout ?

Comment: can you show some code that what are you trying to achieve?